# Do I need to buy Eth for the transaction?

Tags: ether, myetherwallet

recently I've completed my transaction from empowr to ether wallet about 1003 empowr coin in total. But, the real problem is that the money doesn't show up in my wallet. But in etherscan it shows that transaction is success. 
Please help me guys..

Answer (score 1):

What wallet software are you using? It could be that the wallet simply doesn't support the token in question.

To be sure that you have access to it, you can go to the Etherscan page for the token and click "holders." If you see your wallet address in there with the expected amount, then you have control over it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your wallet just holds the private keys of your assets, but the data about your assets balance is actually stored directly on the Blockchain. As a consequence, if your wallet does not regularly connect to Blockchain data, it won't know that your assets changed.

Some wallets automatically scans the most popular ERC20 smart contracts to see if your address is referenced in any of them and update your wallet data accordingly. Some others (like MetaMask for example) require that you manually tell the wallet to check your balance on specific contracts.

Regardless of whether you use a wallet or not, there are 2 ways you can check on Etherscan that you do well own a given token (let's take 0x token as an example):

- Go on the page of the [token holders](https://etherscan.io/token/0xe41d2489571d322189246dafa5ebde1f4699f498#balances) and check that your address appears there
- Go on your address page and check your [token holdings](https://etherscan.io/tokenholdings?a=0x564286362092d8e7936f0549571a803b203aaced)

Both approaches should of course yield the same result. Hope this helps!